# Understanding the Relationship Between Log Records and Modifications a Log Record Can Do

Tags: sql-server, transaction-log

I am currently playing with SQL Server's `fn_dblog` function and have come across a concept that I'm having trouble understanding. In the function's result, there is a 'Page ID' column and a 'Slot ID' column, the combination corresponding to a single log record.

My question is, does this mean that one log record can only (at most) describe the modification of a single row?

I'm trying to gain a deeper understanding of how SQL Server manages and represents data modifications, particularly with regards to the fn_dblog function, so any insights or resources would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> My question is, does this mean that one log record can only (at most) describe the modification of a single row?

In the general sense, yes. There are some log records which aren't made for data pages (for example, growing a file, checkpoint, etc.) and others that will record one change but could affect many items (truncating a table will change a single row [removing the row from metadata] but that will actually remove an entire table of data, page split, etc.). Having said that, the log record is an individual atomic change which is recorded and that's an easy way to think about it.

The best way to learn more is trying a bunch of different things and looking at the log records that were created :)